# Stored procedure - PostgreSQL Query

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm new to stored procedure and want to achieve below ask using stored procedure in PostgreSQL.

I have requirement to calculate difference between 2 time period values like comparative analysis.

**tbl_bv_temp_timeperiod**

| timperiod | p1 | p2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FY 2022 | Q1 2023 | FY 2022 |
| Q1 2023 | H1 2023 | Q1 2023 |
| Q2 2023 | Q2 2023 | Q1 2023 |
| H1 2023 | H1 2023 | FY 2022 |

This table records may increase in future.

I've written a SQL query and output as expected. However, I'm not able to store data into a table

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema.sp_test_bv()
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS $$

    DECLARE

        p1 VARCHAR[]:= ARRAY(SELECT p1 FROM schema.tbl_bv_temp_timeperiod);
        p2 VARCHAR[]:= ARRAY(SELECT p2 FROM schema.tbl_bv_temp_timeperiod); 
        i INT:=1 record;
    
    BEGIN
        SET DATESTYLE TO 'SQL, MDY';
        FOR i IN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.tbl_bv_temp_timeperiod 
            LOOP

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1; 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 as
    (
      SELECT    client, client_sector, segmentation, rank_source, region, asset_class,
        products, currency_pair, product_type, period, period_new, year, bv_rank
      FROM  schema.tbl_bv_temp
      WHERE Period_new = SPLIT_PART(p1[i], ' ', 1) AND 
                year = SPLIT_PART(p1[i], ' ', 2)::int AND 
        bv_rank NOT LIKE ALL(ARRAY['Top%', '%-%', 'Tier%'])
      ORDER BY  client, region, products, product_type

     );

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 as
    (
    SELECT  client, client_sector, segmentation, rank_source, region, asset_class,
        products, currency_pair, product_type, period, period_new, year, bv_rank            
    FROM    schema.tbl_bv_temp
    WHERE   period_new = SPLIT_PART(p2[i], ' ', 1) AND 
                year = SPLIT_PART(p2[i], ' ', 2)::int AND 
        bv_rank NOT LIKE ALL(ARRAY['Top%', '%-%', 'Tier%'])
    ORDER BY    client, region, products, product_type
    );
    

    --Store below query output data into temp table or table and keep appending the 
    --table with output



    SELECT  x.client, x.client_sector, x.segmentation, x.rank_source, x.region, x.asset_class,
            x.products, x.currency_pair, x.product_type, CONCAT(SPLIT_PART(p1[i], ' ', 1), ' ', 
            RIGHT (SPLIT_PART(p1[i], ' ', 2), 2), ' vs. '  SPLIT_PART(p2[i], ' ', 1), ' ', 
                RIGHT(SPLIT_PART(p2[i], ' ', 2), 2)) AS period, 
            CASE    WHEN (x.bv_rank::int - y.bv_rank::int) > 0 THEN CONCAT((x.bv_rank::int - y.bv_rank::int)::VARCHAR, '  ')
              WHEN (x.bv_rank::int - y.bv_rank::int) < 0 THEN CONCAT((x.bv_rank::int - y.bv_rank::int)::VARCHAR, '  ')
          ELSE  CONCAT((x.bv_rank::int - y.bv_rank::int)::VARCHAR, '  ')
          END as bv_rank
    FROM        t1 as x
    LEFT JOIN   t2 as y
    ON  x.client = y.client AND
    x.client_sector = y.client_sector AND
    x.segmentation = y.segmentation AND
    x.rank_source = y.rank_source AND
    x.region = y.region AND
    x.asset_class = y.asset_class AND
    x.products = y.products AND
    x.currency_pair = y.currency_pair AND
    x.product_type = y.product_type 

    RAISE INFO '%', i;
    END LOOP;   
   END;
   $$
```

Please help with below challenge or guide me towards right direction

Comment: This does not look like a *question*. You may need a (paid) consultant to get you started. There is no such thing as a "store procedure", btw. You probably mean "stored procedure", or a "function" to returns rows.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Yes you are correct. I need consultant to get trained on the same. However, i have modified and updated as "Stored Procedure". For Now, can you help me with the query please?

Comment: Sorry, neither is clear what you are trying to do exactly, nor does what I see make any sense. `SELECT COUNT(*)` returns a single row. Looping over that makes no sense. You probably want to loop over elements of the two arrays - which you probably don't need in the first place. You probably also don't need do create new temp tables for every loop. In short, start from scratch. Or hire a consultant.